# Prove that 3 points are in straight line.

Tags: geometry

I am having trouble finding a proper solution to this problem:

An equilateral triangle (ABC) is inscribed in a circle (o). Point D is in the shorter BC arc of circle o. Point E is symmetric to point B about line CD. Prove that points A, D, E are in the same straight line.

**What I already tried:**
In short - I noticed a rhombus and proved that ADE are in the same straight line, because the angle
$$
\measuredangle{ADE}=180^o
$$
My solution is wrong.

Regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $F$ be the point where $CD$ intersects $BE$. This proof relies on [inscribed angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

We have $\angle CDB = 120^\circ$. That means $\angle BDF = 60^\circ$. Therefore, we also have $\angle FDE = 60^\circ$ by symmetry. So $\angle BDE = 120^\circ$. Also, we have $\angle ADB = \angle ACB = 60^\circ$. Therefore we arrive at $\angle ADE = 180^\circ$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

- When you reflect $B$, you get that $|\angle CDE|$ = $|\angle CDB|$.
- Angles $\angle CDB$ and $\angle CDA$ are based on very specific arcs.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: That is a   cool smiley face.

Answer (score 2):

Well, ∠CBA = ∠ACB = 60 deg. => arc AC = arc AB = 120, thus the big arc CB = 240, that means ∠CDB = 1/2 arc CB = 120, because it is an inscribed angle.